# Draw Sri Yantra

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

### Challenge:

Draw **Sri Yantra**.

### How to:

There are different ways to draw it. All include many steps. If you think you can draw it without following the linked steps scroll below for the **elements you must have in your drawing**.

Complete steps can be found here:

http://www.saralhindi.com/Shri_Yantra/makingsky14steps_eng.htm

(*I didn't copied them here because it would become a very long question*, here is [archieve.org mirror in case the first link ever goes down](https://web.archive.org/web/20130807162656/http://www.saralhindi.com/Shri_Yantra/makingsky14steps_eng.htm))

The final picture should look like the picture below:

[image]

### Must have:

Basically any method of drawing of your choosing would be a valid answer providing that you keep the most important elements

1. The number of triangles should the same number as in the above picture (43 smaller triangles resulted from the interlacing of the bigger 9 triangles)
2. This triple intersections are respected:

[image]

3. The tips of the upward triangles touch the bases of the 4 downward triangles and the tips of downward triangles should touch the bases of the 3 upward triangles as shown in the figure bellow.

   [image]
4. The inner circle (bindu) is concentric with the outer circle.
5. The tips (vertices) of the bigger triangles should touch the outer circle:
   [image]
6. The final image should have all the elements and should generally look like:
   [image]
7. Color should be roughly the same as the above image for every element (including petals).
8. The shape of the petals should preferably look roughly like in the image bellow, but can also be just semicircles or simple arc section of circle:
9. There are no strict proportion restrictions to the circles or the size of the gates, but the most outer circle should have the diameter not less than 90% of the side of the outer square, the other elements would be respectively arranged relative to this proportions.

[image]

[image]

### Programming languages and results

There are no restriction to the programming language nor the format of the result (it can be either a vector image, bitmap image, canvas etc) provided that the result is relatively clear and discernible (at least 800px X 800px)

**Latter edit:**
There is no perfect method of drawing as this blog so well explores them:
http://fotthewuk.livejournal.com/
Taking that into account minor faults will be tolerated.

> At this point it as an interesting exercise to learn that it is very probable that there is no perfect solution, much like squaring of the circle.

Comment: I think you'll need to define the colour palette, the relevant length scales of the outer circles and the background and the shape of the petals.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I reedited the question, please tell me if the info is better now. Drawing this Yantra is no easy challenge, and laying the specs is a bit challenging too

Comment: Hi, I know the spec is very tough on this one. But it is required. My recent similar question was also given a hard time because of spec, so its better you come up with one because without that, this is too hard to draw and practically not a real challenge .

Comment: @Optimizer I wish it was that clear as that hat, it will probably close an that's it.

Comment: This challenge is crazy.

Comment: Your picture does not perfectly match the instructions you linked to.  Notice that your two base line vertices of triangle 5 intersect with the innermost circle.  In the instructions, they do not.  Which, if either, should prevail?

Comment: Your coloring pattern is also very different from the one shown on the linked page.

Comment: @DavidCarraher The coloring pattern should be of the one of the step 6, the green square, red & yellow petals, idealy there should be no interesaction, only touching, but minimal deviations and errors would be tolerated where they happen

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu If you use third party units do you have to count that code to add to your score? Note, this isn't code that creates the picture, it's code that will find the point where lines intersect.

Comment: if you use circles, triangles etc, or any other unit as long as you specify where to get that unit, unless it doesn't draw the entire yantra you don't have to add that code to the final score.

Comment: Thanks, got it figured out already though ;) And damn.. this is hard, Only got the triangles done and my code is huge already. Optimizing it now xD

Comment: @TeunPronk That's the hardest part, kudos

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu not sure about that.. not looking forward to those petals haha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19578/discussion-between-eduard-florinescu-and-teun-pronk).

Comment: Indian here, and I see hand-drawn versions of this everywhere (neighborhood grocery shops mostly), so seeing this challenge feels kinda weird :)

Comment: This makes more sense as a code challenge.  Just solving the problem by any means seems challenging enough.

Comment: @DavidCarraher You are probably right, lets see other people opinion we could do the discussion in the above chat so we don't crowd the comment section here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19578/discussion-between-eduard-florinescu-and-teun-pronk

Answer (score 9):

## Mathematica - <s>2836</s> 2536 chars

It was a bit dizzying to figure out the combos of regions that make small triangles available for coloring.

### The Frame

The frame objects are inequalities that describe as regions.  E.g. the red and yellow scalloping are two regions of circles.

```
n1=8;n2=16;
w8=Round[.78 Table[{Cos[2\[Pi] k/n1],Sin[2\[Pi] k/n1]},{k,0,n1-1}],.01];
w16=Round[1 Table[{Cos[2\[Pi] k/n2],Sin[2\[Pi] k/n2]},{k,0,n2-1}],.01];
n=12;y1=.267;
x2=1/Sqrt[2];w=1.8;v=1.85;
pts={{-w,w},{-w/4,w},{-w/4,w+w/8},{-5w/8,w+w/8},{-5w/8,w+5w/24},{5w/8,w+5w/24},{5w/8,w+w/8},{w/4,w+w/8},{w/4,w},
{w,w},{w,w/4},{w+w/8,w/4},{w+w/8,5w/8},{w+5w/24,5w/8},{w+5w/24,-5w/8},{w+w/8,-5w/8},{w+w/8,-w/4},{w,-w/4},
{w,-w},
{w/4,-w},{w/4,-w-w/8},{(5 w)/8,-w-w/8},{(5 w)/8,-w-(5 w)/24},{-((5 w)/8),-w-(5 w)/24},{-((5 w)/8),-w-w/8},{-(w/4),-w-w/8},{-(w/4),-w},{-w,-w},

{-w,-w/4},{-w-w/8,-w/4},{-w-w/8,-5w/8},{-w-5w/24,-5w/8},{-w-5w/24,5w/8},{-w-w/8,5w/8},{-w-w/8,w/4},{-w,w/4}
};
  
frame=RegionPlot[{
(*MeshRegion[pts2,Polygon[Range[20]]],*) (*orange trim *)
MeshRegion[pts,Polygon[Range[Length[pts]]]], (*green box *)
ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2<2.8,{x,y}], (*white, largest circle *)
ImplicitRegion[Or@@(((x-#)^2+(y-#2)^2<.1)&@@@w16),{x,y}], (*yellow scallops*)
ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2<1,{x,y}],(*white circle *)
ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2<1.4,{x,y}],(*white disk*)
ImplicitRegion[Or@@(((x-#)^2+(y-#2)^2<.15)&@@@w8),{x,y}],(*red scallops*)
ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2<1,{x,y}] , (*white disk *)
ImplicitRegion[1.8 < x^2+y^2< 2.2,{x,y}] ,(*brown outer rim*)
ImplicitRegion[2.4 < x^2+y^2< 2.8,{x,y}](*yellow outer rim*)},
BoundaryStyle->Directive[Thickness[.005],Black],
AspectRatio->1,
Frame-> False,
PlotStyle->{(*Lighter@Orange,*)
Darker@Green,White,Yellow,White,White,
Red,White,Lighter@Brown,Yellow,Red,
White,White,White,White,White,
White,White,Red,Red,Darker@Blue,
Darker@Blue,Darker@Blue,Darker@Blue,Darker@Blue,Darker@Blue,
Red,Red,Darker@Blue,Red,Yellow,Red}];
```

Then there is a disk to hide some circles that were used to make the scalloping.

```
Graphics[{White,Disk[{0,0},.99]}]
```

---

### The Innards

Some definitions of vertices and triangles.  Each triangle, t1, t2,... is a distinct region.  Logical operations (`RegionUnion`. `RegionIntersection`, and `RegionDifference`) on large triangles are used to define smaller, triangular cells as derived regions that can be individually colored.

```
p1={-Cos[ArcTan[.267]],y1};
p2={Cos[ArcTan[.267]],y1};
p3={-Cos[ArcTan[.267]],-y1};
p4={Cos[ArcTan[.267]],-y1};
p5={-x2,(x2+y1)/2};
p6={x2,(x2+y1)/2};
p7={-x2,-(x2+y1)/2};
p8={x2,-(x2+y1)/2};
p9={0.5,-x2};
p10={-0.5,-x2};
p11={0.5,-x2};
p12={-0.5,-x2};
p13={a=-.34,b=-.12};
p14={-a,b};
p15={0.5,x2};
p16={-0.5,x2};  
t1=MeshRegion[{{0,-1},p1,p2},Triangle[{1,2,3}]];
t2=MeshRegion[{{0,1},p3,p4},Triangle[{1,3,2}]];
t3=MeshRegion[{{0,-x2},p5,p6},Triangle[{1,3,2}]];
t4=MeshRegion[{{0,x2},p7,p8},Triangle[{1,3,2}]];
t5=MeshRegion[{{0,+y1},p9,p10},Triangle[{1,3,2}]];
t6=MeshRegion[{{0,p5[[2]]},p13,p14},Triangle[{1,3,2}]];
t7=MeshRegion[{{0,p13[[2]]},p15,p16},Triangle[{1,3,2}]];
t8=MeshRegion[{{0,p7[[2]]},{-.33,p1[[2]]-.12},{.33,p1[[2]]-.12}},Triangle[{1,3,2}]];
t9=MeshRegion[{{0,p3[[2]]},{z=-.23,0.063},{-z,.063}},Triangle[{1,3,2}]];
```

---

```
disk=Graphics[{White,Disk[{0,0},.99]}];


innards=RegionPlot[{
t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,(*White*)
RegionDifference[t1,RegionUnion[t5,t4,t2]],(*Blue*)
RegionDifference[t4,RegionUnion[t1,t3,t5]],(*red*)
RegionDifference[t3,RegionUnion[t7,t4,t2]], (*blue*)
RegionDifference[t2,RegionUnion[t1,t7,t3]], (*blue*)
RegionDifference[t5,t1],   (*blue*)
RegionDifference[t4,RegionUnion[t1,t7]], (*Blue *)
RegionDifference[t7,t2],(*Blue*)
RegionDifference[t3,RegionUnion[t1,t2]],(*Blue *)
RegionDifference[t8,t2],  (* blue *)
RegionDifference[t9,t5],  (* red *)
RegionDifference[t9,t6],  (* red *)
RegionIntersection[t4,RegionDifference[t6,t1]], (*blue*)
RegionIntersection[t6,RegionDifference[t5,t8]],  (* red *)
RegionIntersection[t7,t9], (*yellow*)
RegionDifference[RegionIntersection[t7,t8],t5], (*red *)
RegionDifference[RegionIntersection[t5,t6],RegionUnion[t7,t9]],(*red *)
ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2<= .001,{x,y}],  (* smallest circle *) (* red *)
RegionDifference[RegionIntersection[t7,t1 ],t6], (*Red*)
RegionDifference[t8,RegionUnion[t5,t6]],
RegionDifference[t6,RegionUnion[t7,t8]],
RegionDifference[RegionIntersection[t2,t5],RegionUnion[t7,t8]],
RegionDifference[RegionIntersection[t7,t3],t4],
RegionDifference[RegionIntersection[t1,t3],RegionUnion[t5,t4]],
RegionDifference[RegionIntersection[t2,t4],RegionUnion[t7,t3]],
RegionDifference[RegionIntersection[t5,t4],t3]},
BoundaryStyle->Directive[Thickness[.005],Black],
AspectRatio->1,
PlotStyle->{
White,White,White,White,White,White,White,White,White,
Blue,Red,Red,Blue,Blue,Blue,Blue,Blue,Blue,
Red,Red,Blue,Red,Yellow,Red,Red,Red,Blue,Blue,Blue,Blue,Red,Red,Red,Red}]
```

---

### Putting the parts together

```
Show[frame,disk,innards,Graphics[{Brown,Thickness[.02],Line[Append[pts,{-w,w}]]}];
Graphics[{RGBColor[0.92,0.8,0.],Thickness[.015],Line[Append[pts,{-w,w}]]}]]
```

[image: sri4]

---

### Golfed

```
r=ImplicitRegion;m=MeshRegion;t=Triangle;d=RegionDifference;u=RegionUnion;i=RegionIntersection;(*s=ImplicitRegion*)

n1=8;n2=16;w8=.78 Table[{Cos[2\[Pi] k/n1],Sin[2\[Pi] k/n1]},{k,0,n1-1}];
w16=Table[{Cos[2\[Pi] k/n2],Sin[2\[Pi] k/n2]},{k,0,n2-1}];n=12;y1=.267;x2=1/Sqrt[2];w=1.8;v=1.85;
pts={{-w,w},{-w/4,w},{-w/4,w+w/8},{-5w/8,w+w/8},{-5w/8,w+5w/24},{5w/8,w+5w/24},{5w/8,w+w/8},{w/4,w+w/8},{w/4,w},
{w,w},{w,w/4},{w+w/8,w/4},{w+w/8,5w/8},{w+5w/24,5w/8},{w+5w/24,-5w/8},{w+w/8,-5w/8},{w+w/8,-w/4},{w,-w/4},
{w,-w},{w/4,-w},{w/4,-w-w/8},{(5 w)/8,-w-w/8},{(5 w)/8,-w-(5 w)/24},{-((5 w)/8),-w-(5 w)/24},{-((5 w)/8),-w-w/8},{-(w/4),-w-w/8},{-(w/4),-w},{-w,-w},
{-w,-w/4},{-w-w/8,-w/4},{-w-w/8,-5w/8},{-w-5w/24,-5w/8},{-w-5w/24,5w/8},{-w-w/8,5w/8},{-w-w/8,w/4},{-w,w/4}};

frame=RegionPlot[{
m[pts,Polygon[Range[Length[pts]]]], 
r[x^2+y^2<2.8,{x,y}], 
r[Or@@(((x-#)^2+(y-#2)^2<.1)&@@@w16),{x,y}], 
r[x^2+y^2<1,{x,y}],
r[x^2+y^2<1.4,{x,y}],
r[Or@@(((x-#)^2+(y-#2)^2<.15)&@@@w8),{x,y}],
r[x^2+y^2<1,{x,y}] , 
r[1.8 < x^2+y^2< 2.2,{x,y}] ,
r[2.4 < x^2+y^2< 2.8,{x,y}]},
BoundaryStyle->Directive[Thickness[.003],Black],
AspectRatio->1,
Frame-> False,
PlotStyle->{Darker@Green,White,Yellow,White,White,Red,White,Lighter@Brown,Yellow,Red}];

c=Cos[ArcTan[y1]];
p1={-c,y1};
p2={c,y1};
p3={-c,-y1};
p4={c,-y1};
p5={-x2,(x2+y1)/2};
p6={x2,(x2+y1)/2};
p7={-x2,-(x2+y1)/2};
p8={x2,-(x2+y1)/2};
p9={0.5,-x2};
p10={-0.5,-x2};
p11={0.5,-x2};
p12={-0.5,-x2};
p13={a=-.34,b=-.12};
p14={-a,b};
p15={0.5,x2};
p16={-0.5,x2};
t1=m[{{0,-1},p1,p2},t[{1,2,3}]];
t2=m[{{0,1},p3,p4},t[{1,3,2}]];
t3=m[{{0,-x2},p5,p6},t[{1,3,2}]];
t4=m[{{0,x2},p7,p8},t[{1,3,2}]];
t5=m[{{0,+y1},p9,p10},t[{1,3,2}]];
t6=m[{{0,p5[[2]]},p13,p14},t[{1,3,2}]];
t7=m[{{0,p13[[2]]},p15,p16},t[{1,3,2}]];
t8=m[{{0,p7[[2]]},{-.33,p1[[2]]-.12},{.33,p1[[2]]-.12}},t[{1,3,2}]];
t9=m[{{0,p3[[2]]},{z=-.23,0.063},{-z,.063}},t[{1,3,2}]];

innards=RegionPlot[{
d[t1,u[t5,t4,t2]],
d[t4,u[t1,t3,t5]],
d[t3,u[t7,t4,t2]], 
d[t2,u[t1,t7,t3]], 
d[t5,t1],   
d[t4,u[t1,t7]], 
d[t7,t2],
d[t3,u[t1,t2]],
d[t8,t2],  
d[t9,t5],  
d[t9,t6],  
i[t4,d[t6,t1]], 
i[t6,d[t5,t8]],  
i[t7,t9], 
d[i[t7,t8],t5], 
d[i[t5,t6],u[t7,t9]],
r[x^2+y^2<= .001,{x,y}],   
d[i[t7,t1 ],t6], 
d[t8,u[t5,t6]],
d[t6,u[t7,t8]],
d[i[t2,t5],u[t7,t8]],
d[i[t7,t3],t4],
d[i[t1,t3],u[t5,t4]],
d[i[t2,t4],u[t7,t3]],
d[i[t5,t4],t3]},
BoundaryStyle->Directive[Thickness[.003],Black],
Frame->False,
PlotStyle->{Blue,Red,Red,Blue,Blue,Blue,Blue,Blue,Blue,
Red,Red,Blue,Red,Yellow,Red,Red,Red,Blue,Blue,Blue,Blue,Red,Red,Red,Red}];

trim=Graphics[{RGBColor[0.92,0.8,0.],Thickness[.01],Line[Append[pts,{-w,w}]]}];
trim2=Graphics[{Brown,Thickness[.02],Line[Append[pts,{-w,w}]]}];
Show[frame,Graphics[{White,Disk[{0,0},.99]}],trim2,trim,innards]
```

Comment: *innards, and this is completely amazing; have a +1

Comment: Struggling with the colors here aswell, although the inner circle with triangles is all I have so far. I have some catching up to do ;)

Comment: Teun Pronk, It helps to use layers for the frame (everything outside the blue triangles).  The moon-like petals can be achieved by rendering full circles and overlaying them with a large white disk onto which the central figure is rendered.  For me the hardest part is coloring the inner triangular cells.

Comment: Same, really hard. Trying to work out something with recursion but can't get it to work yet.

Comment: @DavidCarraher I fixed the coloring part. Want a tip about it?

Comment: if you have point X,Y you have to check in how many triangles that point is. if its in `0,2,4,6,8` triangles its white. if its in `1` or `5` triangles its blue if its in `3` or `7` triangles its red.

Comment: Interesting observation! Thinking about the triangles a point is in may help set up the logical operations for isolating the cell.